# Purpose of (^) sign in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocoa

I have seen in many iOS header's that (^) is utilized, and I have never come across the reasoning as of why that sign is being used. Would anyone might like to enlighten into this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Those often indicate "blocks". See the [Blocks Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html).

Alternatively, if you watch the beginning of [WWDC 2012 session 712](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=712), they also walk you through blocks with a touch of historical context.

Answer (score 5):

It signifies a block.  A block is a syntax that allows you to create a callback function, and pass it into a method as a parameter. In other languages this is similar to a closure, a lambda, or an anonymous class.

For example a parameter that lists:
`void(^)(NSString *myStr)`
is expecting you to pass in a block/function that returns void, and takes in an NSString pointer.

You can create a block, based on the expected parameters declared in the method, with this syntax:

```
^(<Parameters>) { <Body> }
```

For example, a method that is expecting a block parameter might look like this:

```
-(void)doSomething:(void(^)(NSString *myStr))theBlock;
```

...and could be called like this:

```
[self doSomething:^(NSString *myStr) { NSLog(@"The String is: %@", myStr); }];
```

Your block will be called back from `doSomething:` just like a function, using the parameter name:

```
-(void)doSomething:(void(^)(NSString *myStr))theBlock {
  theBlock(@"Hello!");
}
```

...which would display:

```
The String is: Hello!
```

Answer (score 3):

The ^ character is used for blocks, in particular, block parameters.

Comment: Aah, thats the concept I haven't touched in a while, so sort of forgot about it. Thanks. Btw, Rob, thanks for pointing out to the topic.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking why the character '^' for use in blocks, it's because there's relatively few characters left that:

1. Are available on all typical keyboards.
2. Could be used at all - i.e. aren't already significant in the language and would conflict.
3. Don't look stupid.

That actually narrows it down to only two or three, and of those '^' was chosen because, well, because.

There's probably a record of this on the llvm.org mailing lists and so forth, if you want to pore over the discussion in detail.

You could also look at the minutes from the C++11 committee meetings on lambdas, which went through basically the same process.